# How to write to console a custom array type

Tags: vhdl

I am fairly new to VHDL and I am running some snippets from a code I was given to see what it is doing. There is a custom array type I want to see in the console, but I get and error when I try to write it.

```
entity hello_world is 
end entity hello_world;

library STD;                          
library IEEE;                        
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;           
use STD.textio.all;                  
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;         
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;                                    

architecture test of hello_world is 

    type row_type is array(0 to 2)  of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    type new_type is array(0 to 1)  of row_type;
    signal  max_new : new_type := (others => (others => (others => '0')));

    begin
    my_print :  process is                  
        variable my_line : line;    
        begin
            write(my_line, string'("Value of max_new"));      
            write(my_line, max_new);    
            writeline(output, my_line);            
            wait;
    end process my_print;
end architecture test;
```

The error I get while running the simulation is:

 Error: type error near 'max_new': expected type 'std_ulogic'. Error: formal 'l' of mode inout must have an associated actual. Error: formal 'value' has no actual or default value. Error: indexed name prefix type 'void' is not an array type
[image]

If I understood correctly, row type is an array of size 3, in each position I have a vector made of 4 bits. new_type is an array of size 2, in each position I have a row_type, which is an array of size 3 with a 4 bits vector in each position. Is this correct? Since it is initialized to 0, I expect to see only that.

I am using Vivado 2018.3 for the simulation.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function *write* of std.textio can take the following arguments as value (https://www.hdlworks.com/hdl_corner/vhdl_ref/VHDLContents/TEXTIOPackage.htm) :

- bit
- bit_vector
- boolean
- character
- integer
- real
- string
- time

IEEE.std_logic_textio add std_logic and his derivated to this list but Array is not handled by *write*.

You can print your array like that :

```
my_print :  process is                  
  variable my_line : line;    
begin
  write(my_line, string'("Value of max_new"));
  for I in 0 to 1 loop
    for J in 0 to 2 loop 
      write(my_line, max_new(I)(J));
    end loop;
  end loop;    
  writeline(output, my_line);            
  wait;
end process my_print;
```

Comment: This is just what I needed, thanks. Just for the record, this is the output:
Value of max_new
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000

Answer (score 2):

You could also author your own write procedure:

```vhdl
entity hello_world is
end entity hello_world;

-- library STD;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use STD.textio.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
-- use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

architecture test of hello_world is

    type row_type is array(0 to 2)  of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    type new_type is array(0 to 1)  of row_type;
    signal  max_new : new_type := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
    procedure write (l: inout line; new_type_val: in new_type)  is
    begin
        write (l, string'("("));
        for i in new_type'range loop
            write (l, string'("("));
            for j in row_type'range loop
                write (l, string'(""""));
                write(l, new_type_val(i)(j));
                write (l, string'(""""));
                if j /= row_type'right then
                    write(l, string'(","));
                end if;
            end loop;
            write (l, string'(")"));
            if i /= new_type'right then
                write(l, string'(","));
            end if;
        end loop;
        write (l, string'(")"));
    end procedure;

    begin
my_print:
    process is
        variable my_line: line;
    begin
        write(my_line, string'("Value of max_new = "));
        write(my_line, max_new);
        writeline(output, my_line);
        wait;
    end process my_print;
end architecture test;
```

```
ghdl -r  hello_world
Value of max_new = (("0000","0000","0000"),("0000","0000","0000"))
```

using preexisting write procedure overloads as building blocks.

You can also use type specific conversions to strings eliminating the dependence on Synopsys package std_logic_textio as well as introducing the ability to use report statements:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

architecture no_std_logic_textio of hello_world is
    type row_type is array(0 to 2)  of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    type new_type is array(0 to 1)  of row_type;
    signal  max_new : new_type := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
    -- For VHDL version < -2008:
    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is 
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;
    
    function to_string (nt:  new_type) return string is
        variable l: line;
    begin
        write (l, string'("("));
        for i in new_type'range loop
            write (l, string'("("));
            for j in row_type'range loop
                write (l, '"' & to_string(nt(i)(j)) & '"');
                if j /= row_type'right then
                    write(l, string'(","));
                end if;
            end loop;
            write (l, string'(")"));
            if i /= new_type'right then
                write(l, string'(","));
            end if;
        end loop;
        write (l, string'(")"));
        return l.all;
    end function;
begin
my_print:
    process is
        variable my_line: line;
    begin
        write (my_line, string'("value of max_new = "));
        write(my_line, to_string(max_new));
        writeline(output, my_line);
        report LF & HT & "max_new = " & to_string(max_new);
        wait;
    end process my_print;
end architecture no_std_logic_textio;
```

And this demonstrates both writing to `output` and a report statement:

```
ghdl -r hello_world
value of max_new = (("0000","0000","0000"),("0000","0000","0000"))
hello_world.vhdl:95:9:@0ms:(report note):
    max_new = (("0000","0000","0000"),("0000","0000","0000"))
```